# How can I make htaccess Dynamic and Static rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this dynamic rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC]
```

and I am trying to add some static rules like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /construction/pools.html http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction-services/pools
```

---

The problem is when I type the following in the address bar:

`http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction/pools.html`

then apache redirects to:

`http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction-services/pools?sub=construction&second=pools.html`

What I want is apache redirects to:

```
http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction-services/pools
```

---

Does anybody know why?

Thank you.

Comment: Do your dynamic URLs ever end in `.html`?

Comment: No, those are like this: /construction/pools

Comment: Ok, it ought to work as I have added below. Maybe need `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects are processed in the order they appear, so it should work to place the static redirect before the `RewriteRule`.  Don't for get the `[L]` flag on your `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Match the static redirect first
RedirectMatch 302 /construction/pools.html http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction-services/pools

# Since your dynamic URLs don't end in .html, avoid those with RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC,L]
```

Or you could do it without the `RewriteCond` if none of your dynamic urls have a `.`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I need you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379842/why-if-i-put-a-dash-in-a-rule-in-my-htaccess-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

Write the htaccess rule based on priority ( place the rule which has common behavior at last)

In your case

```
RedirectMatch 302 /construction/pools.html http://www.{samedomain}.com/construction-services/pools
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC]
```