# Why if I put a "-" dash in a rule in my htaccess doesn't work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rules, the one "our-stores" redirects to a different place than the other "PLAIN PAGES" rules:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RedirectMatch 302 /construction.html http://www.{website}.com/construction-services
    RedirectMatch 302 /construction/endless-pools.html http://www.{website}.com/construction-services/endless-pools

    # PRODUCT AND SERVICES
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC]

    # PLAIN PAGES
    #RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^signup-free$ /signup-free.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^about$ /content.php?page=1 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^links$ /content.php?page=2 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /portfolio.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^our-stores$ /our-stores.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^products-list$ /lists.php?action=products [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^services-list$ /lists.php?action=services [L,NC]
```

When I type `/our-stores` apache redirects to: `/our-stores/?sub=our-stores&second=`

I don't get it because the rest (signup-free, about, links, portfolio... and so on) are working fine.

Can anybody help me with this one?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried it without a hyphen? did that help?  have you checked the server logs? (sometimes if there's a bug in your htaccess, you can get clues about the problem from there)

Comment: Move the generic RewriteRule and its associated RewriteCond  _below_ all the specific ones so it is matched last.  Also, those two `RewriteCond` up at the top beneath `RewriteBase` are not doing anything . They should probably be before the `REQUEST_URI` condition...

Comment: It looks like you typed `our-stores/` with a trailing slash, and that was matched by the generic rule.

Comment: But then does signup-free work correctly? It follows the same pattern.  The generic rule belongs at the bottom anyway, as a catch-all.

Comment: That is completly true, I have changed the htaccess as you mentioned, I have tried with htaccess.madewithlove.be and it should work fine, but is still the same problem. it links to: /our-stores/?sub=our-stores&second=

Comment: The problem is the file's name, if I remove the hyphen in the file, and change the rule ourstores instead of our-stores, then it works fine, but I need to name it our-stores, why is the problem in the file's name?

Comment: my problem is not solved, it still happening the same issue. To make it work I must to put: RewriteRule ^ourstores$ /ourstores.php [L,NC]

Comment: @human I put in an answer that formalizes some of this discussion, and improves the generic rule a bit.

Comment: @human I also hate htaccess. I have a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814715/htaccess-breaks-with-an-escaped-dash-in-the-redirect-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic rule has been moved to the bottom, and the `REQUEST_FILENAME` conditions moved beneath the static redirects.  Further, I have added a `/?` to match an optional trailing slash on each of the specific redirects.  Finally, the generic rule is improved not to use `.*`, but rather to match everything up to the first `/` in a less greedy way. Then it uses `.+` after the `/` to make sure at least one character is present.  Urls with a trailing slash would therefore not match it.  If you have some generics without a `second=`, change back to `.*`.

All of these work correctly in the htaccess tester.

```
RedirectMatch 302 /construction.html http://www.{website}.com/construction-services
RedirectMatch 302 /construction/endless-pools.html http://www.{website}.com/construction-services/endless-pools

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^signup-free/?$ /signup-free.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /content.php?page=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^links/?$ /content.php?page=2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$ /portfolio.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^our-stores/?$ /our-stores.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products-list/?$ /lists.php?action=products [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^services-list/?$ /lists.php?action=services [L,NC]

# PRODUCT AND SERVICES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: I have tried to copy and paste your code into my htaccess file, but when I do so, the whole webpage gets destroyed, no css, images, or javascript, only content is visible. but if I put the REQUEST_FILENAME  rules just above the REQUEST_URI, everything works fine except the bloody "our-stores" rule. Still Redirect loop.

Comment: @human `our-stores` does a redirect loop? That's different from before.  Do you have any other .htaccess upstream or downstream of this? Something that matches `our-stores.php` explicitly and redirects to `/our-stores`.

Comment: Yes something has changed, because the redirection is fine in my direction bar appears /our-stores after all, but I get the same message Redirect Loop., I have no more htaccess files, do you think I am missing something?

Comment: You'll have to look at your server log to see what is being requested in the redirect loop. Also `RewriteLog /path/to/logs/rewrite.log` `RewriteLogLevel 5` to see what is being matched. There is something else somewhere which is causing the loop for that page only.

Comment: @human I am not sure if this helps, but I am testing it in a real server and get this: `'REQUEST_URI' => string '/Test/our-stores' (length=16)` and `'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/Test/our-stores.php' (length=20)`. So it works with no problem with the rule and the position indicated in this answer. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before the tests.

Answer (score 1):

The sign "-" is a special character in   regular expression. It defines a range (a-z, à-9, etc).

Try to escape it.

```
RewriteRule ^our\-stores$ /our-stores.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: yes, my escaping character was not displayed on my initial response.

Comment: the hyphen is only a special character in regex when it's within a character class -- ie within square brackets `[]`. It shouldn't need escaping otherwise.

Comment: also, this answer doesn't explain why `our-stores` didn't work but `signup-free` and others do work.

Comment: it still doesn't work, same behavior, redirect loop. 
RewriteRule ^our\-stores$ /our-stores.php [L,NC]
I am doing something wrong, for sure.

Comment: This fixed my problem where I would redirect 2 page (eg page-1 and page1) to a different page. Page-1 would beredirected to the page1-redirect. Adding the escape character to the hyphen fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have an actual file (or more likely an empty directory) named `our-stores`.

This would trigger the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, resulting in it not rewriting.

It would then try to load the default page from that directory (eg index.php), which doesn't exist, and so it would try to rewrite that, resulting in the `?sub=our-stores&second=` paramters being added.

Comment: Hi SDC, I have no folders or files named our-stores.