# Can not get variable from .htaccess generated url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get new url using `.htaccess` file but I can't get php variable name from the url. 
**.htaccess code is here**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^courses/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ courses.php?cat-name=$1
```

**php code is**

```
echo $_GET['cat-name'];
```

But showing error undefined index cat-name. my url is `http://www.mywebsite.com/courses/php/`. So how can I access the php variable?

Comment: Your need to escape the minus, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379842/why-if-i-put-a-dash-in-a-rule-in-my-htaccess-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you victim of `MultiViews` options here. Disable it by using:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.