# htaccess breaks with (an escaped) dash in the redirect URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a set of URLs that are in the form www.website.co.uk/businessname

and these are meant to do a htaccess Proxy redirect to pull data from another domain on the server.

This is what I have:

```
#Start Business pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.outputside.org.uk/swellcottage$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.outputsite.org.uk/hawthorn-books$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P]
#End Business Pages
```

The first rule works perfectly, displaying the contents of `http://www.datasite.co.uk/swellcottage` on the URL `www.outputsite.org.uk/swellcottage` but the second rule/condition doesn't work.

I looked at escaping the `-` character in the URL as so:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.outputsite.org.uk/hawthorn\-books$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P]
    #End Business Pages
```

But this still doesn't seem to engage correctly, the rewrite rules do not work and the site replies with the fallback 404 that the page `www.outputsite.org.uk/hawthorn-books` does not exist.

Where else and how else should I escape the dash or otherwise what's wrong with my syntax here? cheers

ps. I have it that filenames (index.php) and folder names (/places/) are not subject to the proxy redirects .

### UPDATE

I have more Rules in my htaccess:

```
#to add www. to each request. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

#Start biz pages
...
#End biz Pages

#to prevent error looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

I have also run the same code above with `hawthornbooks` without the dash, escaped or otherwise and the code works correctly, so I need to find out the correct way of escaping the dash character. All code and work is UTF-8.

NOTE: This issue appears similar to [Why if I put a "-" dash in a rule in my htaccess doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379842/why-if-i-put-a-dash-in-a-rule-in-my-htaccess-doesnt-work) but I found no solution to that problem.

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: THere are rules to ensure `www.` is used and rules to stop error looping. I am 99% sure the error is the `-` symbol but I can't seem to escape it correctly.

Comment: No hyphen is not the problem but other rules or code can be.

Comment: I disagree - I ran the same htaccess with `hawthornbooks` and it works fine, that dash is causing the break, but I can't see where. I will update my question for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If problem is just a hyphen this should work:

```
#Start Business pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?outputside\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(swellcottage)/?$ http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?outputside\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(hawthorn.books)/?$ http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P,NC]
#End Business Pages
```

Comment: I retried it and it work, I think I needed to give your solution time to update htaccess on the server. Your solution solves the issue, but I don't know why the dash causes such hassle!

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to be a temporary rather than a permanent solution, but you might try the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.outputsite.org.uk/hawthorn([^\/]*)\/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.datasite.co.uk/$1 [P]
```

This will look for any URI which conforms to the pattern `www.outputsite.org.uk/hawthorn` followed by any number of characters (or zero characters) which *aren't* `/` and then ending with an (optional) `/`.

Comment: Thanks. I may take this up, but business names are the variable for getting the data from the database on the data site so I don't want them to be vague, if possible. I'd-and they'd- dislike if `/hawthorn_bottom_sucker` came up with the business page!!