# htaccess - Rewrite URLs with query parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rule to rewrite URLs which works for single word parameters. However, it doesn't work if there is a "-" in the variable. How can I modify this to accomplish this?

Old URL:
`domain.com/medications/?drug=medication-title`

New URL:
`domain.com/medications/medication-title`

```
RewriteRule ^medications/([^/d]+)/?$ medications/?drug=$1 [QSA]
```

Like I said, it works when there is no "-" in the name, but need it to handle all passed parameters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379842/why-if-i-put-a-dash-in-a-rule-in-my-htaccess-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regex by using this rule in root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^medications/([^/]+)/?$ medications/?drug=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me an internal server error. If I add the "d" back into the ([^/d]+) aspects, it will process the single word parameters, but not the ones with the "-".

Comment: After doing some testing, I found a different issue that I missed before. Some of the medication names have a "/" in the title. So, with the rewrite it now treats it as a new subfolder. Is there a way to escape those, change them to a "-" or something along those lines?

Comment: Hmm that should be covered in a new question as I think that rule will be a bit complex and very different from this one. Once you open a new question I will try to address it there.